# Win 7 Reinstallation DVD?

Tags: installation-package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a Dell reinstallation disk for Windows Vista on a Sony laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/38596/using-a-dell-reinstallation-disk-for-windows-vista-on-a-sony-laptop)

Can a Dell Reinstallation Windows 7 Home Premium DVD be used for a clean install on a non-branded home built PC or must it be used only on a Dell PC as it says on the label. If I open the package, I cannot return it.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think it will work. Those manufacturer specific discs have something that they look for in the BIOS I think. I'm not  exactly sure what, but somehow the manufacturer "signs" their computers and the disc looks for that signature.

Your computer won't have that signature so it won't work.

Comment: They also *aren't a generic Windows image anyway* - they have the OEM specific stuff on them!

Comment: `They also aren't a generic Windows image anyway - they have the OEM specific stuff on them!`   Actually, the Windows discs *are* generic, at least the can be. They do indeed usually have OEM-specific stuff (like tons of shareware junkware), but they *can be* a raw Windows disc with nothing different other than the key built-in.

Comment: `Those manufacturer specific discs have something that they look for in the BIOS I think. I'm not exactly sure what, but somehow the manufacturer "signs" their computers and the disc looks for that signature.`   It’s called the [SLIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS#SLIC); it is a signature in the DMI of the BIOS. If you are going to use the OEM key, then you *must* have it in place, however its presence does not prevent you from using a different key you bought separately ([at least not before Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/512123/)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but it will not work because that disk is made for a Dell Computer, using it on another computer will result into failure.

Comment: A sticker attached to the package states" This is a full version software. It can be used for a NEW INSTALLATION or reinstallation. This software can be installed on any PC.  I don't know whether to trust that sticker. If it open I can't return it.

Comment: I would do a simple thing, call the support to be sure I can use that cd like it's written on the sticker. Then I would use it

Comment: If it doesn't install properly, you should be able to return it as defective. The wording on the label is very clear.

Comment: Yes, the label is clear. Guess I will try it. Then I can at least rate the seller.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Dell branding does not mean that it will not work.  The Dell DVDs activate only on OEM keys, so if you have a PC with an OEM key on a label (which is typically for the big manufacturers) a clean install should work and once you enter your OEM key it should activate.

If you don't have an OEM key label or a legitimate key to work with you are pirating Windows no matter what disk you use.

There are really 5 types of activation for Windows Vista/7: OEM, Retail, Upgrade, Enterprise KMS, Enterprise MAK.  You should be aware that OEM keys only activate on one cpu type either 32 bit or 64 bit but not both, whereas retail would activate on both.